# Python correct version of pip. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.2.0 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

[ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.2.0 (from versions: none)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.2.0]

[Screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xlyv.png)

I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Have you upgraded your pip?

Comment: Yes my pip is in its latest version 20.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

`mkl-fft` at PyPI doesn't have version 1.2.0. [The latest version currently](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/#history) is 1.0.6. Perhaps you want to install [from Github](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft/releases/tag/v1.2.0)?

```
pip install 'git+https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git@v1.2.0#egg=mkl_fft-1.2.0'
```